# Simple Proxy Server in Flutter

Tags: flutter, proxy

Can We Create proxy app to connect with custom proxy servers in flutter?

I have tried flutter_vpn package on pub dev
but want to create custom proxy app that can connect with custom proxy server and also able to set proxy per specific apps in flutter
is it possible with flutter?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.